# After showing adsense video ad,I cant click buttons which are covered by the AD

Tags: javascript, css, adsense

I followed google's tutorial and succeed to show video AD in my website.However,I cant click buttons which are covered by the AD,when the AD is over.

This is the index.html

```
<canvas id="GameCanvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" tabindex="0"></canvas>
<div id="splash">
<div class="progress-bar stripes">
  <span style="width: 0%"></span>
</div>
</div>
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="content">
    <video id="contentElement" playsinline muted>
      <source src="http://rmcdn.2mdn.net/Demo/vast_inspector/android.mp4"></source>
      <source src="http://rmcdn.2mdn.net/Demo/vast_inspector/android.webm"></source>
    </video>
  </div>
  <div id="adContainer"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js"></script>
<script src="src/settings.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This is .css

```
#mainContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
}

#content, #adContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
}

#contentElement {
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ad is over why do not hide the container?